# Pinging a website through a proxy server( with authentication) using Python

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, icmp

I'm new and just learning the ropes with python programming and this was something I'm trying to do.

My internet is through a proxy server which requires authentication. How do I ping a website, for example 'www.google.com' using Python and check if it's successful?

P.S. my OS is windows

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to include what version of python you're running too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib2
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'http://login:password@my-proxy:port/'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
try:
    f = opener.open("http://google.com/")
    f.read(1)
    print "Success"
except Exception:
    print "Failed"
```